# how to write data on a specific sheet of a spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script

I have created a list of data that I want to write on specific sheet(or should I say tabs ?) of a spreadsheet.

I wan't to send each row of the `DATA_TO_WRITE` list to the corresponding sheet in the list `SHEET_TO_GET`, and of course, when I have 2/3/...10 row I want all of them to stack on the sheet.

here is the code I try :

```
  var SHEET_TO_GET = [['ALPINES MUSEUM DAV'],
          ['ALPINES MUSEUM DAV'],
          ['BLOIS_MAQUETTE'],
          ['BELVEDERE MUSEUM'],
          ['BELVEDERE MUSEUM']];

 var DATA_TO_WRITE = [['2D', "MAREIKE", '50', '33.0'],
          ['PROJECT MANAGEMENT', "LOUISE", '50', '16.5'],
          ['PROJECT MANAGEMENT', "MAREIKE", '50', '6.0'],
          ['FABRICATION', "MAREIKE", '50', '6.0'],
          ['2D', "MAREIKE", '50', '31.5']];

  var target = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var target_sheet = target.getSheetByName(SHEET_TO_GET)

  target_sheet.getRange(4, 1, 1, 4).setValue(DATA_TO_WRITE);
```

Of course it didn't work. What should I do to make it works to have this kind of result if I consider only the sheet `ALPINES MUSEUM DAV`

[image]

Comment: is MATERIAL always below the last one?

Comment: @Cooper, yes it is !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
function myfunck() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const ns = ['Sheet0', 'ALPINES MUSEUM DAV', 'BLOIS_MAQUETTE', 'BELVEDERE MUSEUM', 'BELVEDERE MUSEUM'];
  const vs = [['2D', "MAREIKE", '50', '33.0'],
  ['PROJECT MANAGEMENT', "LOUISE", '50', '16.5'],
  ['PROJECT MANAGEMENT', "MAREIKE", '50', '6.0'],
  ['FABRICATION', "MAREIKE", '50', '6.0'],
  ['2D', "MAREIKE", '50', '31.5']];
  ns.forEach((n, i) => {
    let sh = ss.getSheetByName(n);
    let col1 = sh.getRange("A1:A" + sh.getLastRow()).getValues().flat();
    let nr = col1.indexOf("MATERIAL") + 1;
    sh.insertRowBefore(nr);
    sh.getRange(nr, 1, 1, vs[i].length ).setValues([vs[i]]);
  });
}
```